# How to minimize the white space from boxchart in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, boxplot

I would like to minimize the whitespace of the figure (boxchart).  I have tried to get a transparent background using built-in function `exportgraphics()`:

https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/save-figure-with-minimal-white-space.html

But it doesn't work. Instead, it gives the following error:

```
Warning: Background transparency is not supported; using white instead.
```

I wonder if someone help me to remove the white space from the figure?
Thank you in advance.

```
 clc; clear; close;

% data
D1= [0.944790802    0.557698361 0.373906779 2.046704837 2.301581619 1.527444403 1.209060357 0.255009648 0.006522648 1.391635043 0.020485623 3.06E-05    2.219570211 0.031292703 1.4617617   0.709825512 0.140968679 0.39152202  0.118959281 0.604265713 0.108340057 1.254792134 0.187867762 0.391214936 0.527749647 0.284452271 0.137486525 1.50698204  0.398872235 1.09E-05    6.030073741 0.343347524 2.66E-05    0.244522229 1.828567513 0.384888011 0.150066426 0.458832813 0.039189943 1.356957639 0.162054596 0.547751882 3.835735492 0.038394762 0.661566595 0.13553248  0.270139424 1.451613168 0.044339379 0.413170264 1.795609121 0.109564539 0.201333355 1.207746569 0.812164457 0.003902586 3.508953738 0.024859534 1.193314027 ]';
D2= [0.523944609    1.423099939 1.869691969 0.920446948 1.977619794 0.781737256 0.95977679  1.100075857 0.017899515 4.533151907 0.03790224  2.80E-05    3.432894823 0.120809324 2.359138901 1.530822669 0.24903375  3.017043435 0.357091919 1.775763839 0.067044341 2.383827733 0.496209584 1.016302313 2.17366118  0.718760335 0.316183758 1.662342228 0.658886019 1.57E-05    1.798207987 2.194711665 3.12E-05    0.777365181 1.31022147  1.803898883 0.142538755 1.633823624 0.095730818 1.917168272 1.066430117 1.570445025 0.67080804  0.028328869 0.265164055 1.313050736 0.988211581 1.355540089 0.180799139 1.559261863 2.765900536 0.275343017 0.828076679 1.749404233 1.276678701 0.003919396 4.740058349 0.059366823 1.978131529 ]';
D3 = [7.503974554   2.43552972  8.907981809 10.82563814 11.09197623 18.18846472 6.084768631 5.464296776 4.067161596 14.26678079 2.792424541 0.572435047 2.733751731 3.559015982 2.505767574 5.449188972 2.786168085 12.06056623 9.470572167 3.116171421 0.458594772 0.434307287 3.447147643 5.200432201 6.18563517  19.19753749 3.656691267 4.967834173 10.29317107 2.121656326 1.394653476 2.790630109 3.152455521 2.082149563 5.232312376 1.259368399 6.269558563 3.251263155 3.898594351 10.54554845 10.20258999 6.661139665 4.464739104 1.665067753 8.608715167 8.084037724 2.402608378 7.60967001  7.554079841 6.05757598  3.768961429 3.502224334 1.027846476 1.537041705 17.67476646 1.538015623 15.93866248 6.015687282 6.338130064 ]';
data = [D1 D2 D3];

% Requires R2019b or later
t = tiledlayout(2,2, 'Padding', 'none', 'TileSpacing', 'compact'); 

%box chart 
b=boxchart(data);

b.BoxFaceColor = [0 0.4470 0.7410];
b.WhiskerLineColor  = [0.17 0.17 0.17];
b.MarkerColor = [0 0.4470 0.7410];%black
b.JitterOutliers = 'on';
b.MarkerStyle = '.';
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y ')
title('Transparent background')

% Requires R2020a or later
exportgraphics(t,'boxPlot.jpg','BackgroundColor','none')
```

Comment: Which white space? Outside the axes or inside? Showing your actual result and expected result would be useful to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to maximize chart space, you may manipulate the axis location, as seen in the following code. If exporting transparency is also required, use the PDF format.

```
figure()
b=boxchart(data);
b.BoxFaceColor = [0 0.4470 0.7410];
b.WhiskerLineColor  = [0.17 0.17 0.17];
b.MarkerColor = [0 0.4470 0.7410];%black
b.JitterOutliers = 'on';
b.MarkerStyle = '.';
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y ')
ax.Position=[0.07,0.1,0.92,0.9];
```

[image: Maximized axis]